# How do you make a seamless IK > FK > IK switch using drivers?

Tags: rigging, drivers, pose-mode

Is there a way to have a seamless IK, to FK, to IK, to FK, etc... kind of slider? I have seen it to be done in riggify but it uses a python script that only works with that armature and doesnt look very clean. is there a method to do this without the need of scripting and by solely using drivers?

I have tried to do this by having 2 arms, one with IK and the other one with FK. the FK one was supposed to copy the IK one's pose when you switched them, it worked, and vise versa for the IK to copy the FK pose. but I have only been able to achieve FK > IK, and not FK > IK > FK. is it possible with only drivers?

Comment: The problem with blender drivers is that if set on a property, they have sole control of that property. There is no way to manually override it later. This is why rigify uses the snapping script to make IK follow FK and vice versa, it retains the user's ability to manually update the bones.