# Is it possible to use both FK and IK on same frame

Tags: animation, rigging

I have quadruped I want to animate. I made FK and IK bones and switch slider which toggles FK or IK via driver. On frame 1, I want my left leg to use IK and my right leg to use FK since I can't properly pose it only with IK. However, when I pose my IK leg to wanted position and start sliding my switch, that leg goes to rest position. What is way to avoid that, is it possible and how?
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe show some pictures, or even share your armature

Comment: Thank you for your time, I uploaded file. Hope you will manage to orientate in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, and it is possible to imitate the rigify IK switch plus position swap.  However it's much simpler to just add the IK switch.

The trick is to use four bone chains and rely on how the constraint stack is processed for the switching.  (You can do it with 3 chains if you merge the DEF chain with the switch chain but this is easier to explain.)

[image: Image showing the four chains of bones]

I've shown each chain of bones offset from the others, but in the end they all overlay, so that each thigh bone has exactly the same position.

- The `DEF` chain: these are the deformation bones.  They are the ones that the body mesh is parented to.  They copy transforms from the equivalent `MCH switch` bones.
- The `MCH switch` chain: these are the chain that allows the switch to be implemented without introducing dependency cycles.  They copy transforms from *both* the `IK` and `FK` equivalent bones.
- The `MCH IK` chain: This is your IK chain.  You should only manipulate the `CTRL IK.leg` bone in pose mode and only when you have the switch set to IK.  The remainder follow the chain.
- The `CTRL FK` chain: This is your FK chain.  You can manipulate each of these bones in pose mode and only when you have the switch set to FK.

The "secret" is that constraints act in the same order they're placed on the stack. So if you place a Copy Transforms constraint on the MCH bone to copy from the equivalent IK bone and then you place a Copy Transforms constraint after it to copy from the equivalent FK bone, you can use the influence value of the second copy transforms as a "switch".  Set to 1, the MCH bone follows the FK bone.  Set to 0, the MCH bone follows the IK bone.

[image: Constraint order for the switch bones]

You can switch between IK and FK simply by changing the influence on the second constraint, but there are four bones that need to be set to the same value, so a driver can be used.

To create the driver, hover over the value of the custom property, RMB and select copy as driver from the drop down menu.  Then go to each influence to be driven, in the other three bones, hover over the value and select paste driver.

A common technique is to use a custom property to drive the first bone's influence so that you don't have to find the constraint bone to change the value.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That's a lot of content I need to try it and then get back and see if it worked.

Comment: Love how straightforward and informative your answer is. It made me curious too. Really well done!

Comment: @DarkSoul thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiair with Rigify? It's a add on that also makes use of both IK and FK bones.

The issue you're having is that when you pose IK bones, the FK bones remain the same.

Rigify has a button that can copy the pose of the IK bones to the FK bones. See below.
[image]
[image]

You can also do vice-versa. I highly recommend using Rigify. On top of that, rigify even has a quadruppled rigs.

It's a free addon and saved me lots of trouble.

Comment: Almost sounds like an advert, lol

Comment: So basically, my left leg can use FK and my right leg can use IK at same time? I know it is great, but I haven't use it, and now my custom rig is finished, and making it again from Rigify would again take me a lot of time. Since I need to add all those constraints I already have in my model...

Comment: I have seen the rig you uploaded. If I were in your shoes, I wouldn't start from scratch, unless it's easy. If you can somehow figure out what method is used by rigify, then you can recreate that in your own rig. I'm not exactly sure how it's done. But there are several ways.

Comment: I think same. I don't have time, neither enough patience to start again :D Hope there is some way to achieve this. Probably has to be, since rigify has it, there is no reason custom rig can't have it

Comment: I found this :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140368/how-do-you-make-a-seamless-ik-fk-ik-switch-using-drivers. It seems that snapping method uses a python scripts. I have no experience in that, i'm sorry!

Comment: Or mayeb there is a way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vdHwHSMeRQ&ab_channel=PierrickPicaut

Comment: If there is a way, Picaut will know it.  The answer that I just posted is my take on his approach.